# Identify integers in column and replace with string

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to python and pandas. I have a dataframe that looks as follows:

```
             ID                    NAME
0      0000001                    Apple
1      0000002                       35
2      0000003                    Grape
3      0000004                       22
4      0000005                   Banana
5      0000006                       12
```

My goal is to replace the fields with numbers in the NAME column with 'Unknown'

So far, I have tried the following:

```
out['NAME'] = out.apply(lambda x: x['NAME'].replace(x['NAME'], 'Unknown'))
```

But it wouldn't seem to replace it and gives me a KeyError: ('NAME', 'occurred at index ID')

Ultimately I am expecting an output as follows:

```
             ID                    NAME
0      0000001                    Apple
1      0000002                   Unkown
2      0000003                    Grape
3      0000004                   Unkown
4      0000005                   Banana
5      0000006                   Unkown
```

Comment: strictly integers or any number, like what about 11.0 (floats that perfectly represent integers) or 11.1 a float that cant be an integer

Comment: to clarify, in my case it's just integers (10, 11, 12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out['NAME']=np.where(out.NAME.str.contains('\d'),'unknown',out.NAME)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.Series.str.isnumeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isnumeric.html):

```
>>> out.loc[out.NAME.str.isnumeric(), 'NAME'] = 'Unknown'
>>> out

        ID     NAME
0  0000001    Apple
1  0000002  Unknown
2  0000003    Grape
3  0000004  Unknown
4  0000005   Banana
5  0000006  Unknown
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) to determinate which rows can be converted to numeric:

```
>>> df.loc[~pd.to_numeric(df["NAME"], errors = "coerce").isnull(), "NAME"] = "unknown"
>>> df
   ID     NAME
0   1    Apple
1   2  unknown
2   3    Grape
3   4  unknown
4   5   Banana
5   6  unknown
```

With `errors = "coerce"` the invalid parsing will be set to `NaN`.

Answer (score 0):

You can  also just create a function in python

```
def replaceName(Name):
 if Name.isnumeric():
  return "Unknown"
 else:
  return Name
```

and use the map function:

```
df["Name"] = df["Name"].map(lambda x: replaceName(x))
```

Comment: i only need this for a single use case. Is there any other particular benefit to making it a function besides reusability?

Comment: For functional programming, it is great to use Python one-liners. If you want to go back and deconstruct what you've done or make changes then functions can be preferable.